# CSS/HTML: Dynamic `hat` border on hover of menu item

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a basic menu, with a 'hat' border that appears at the top of the menu on `:hover`

The border is not a straight line but has a (**round**) bump in the center and appears as so (**basically like a hat**): `__/\__`, when it appears over a bigger menu name it looks like so: `_____/\_____`

I would like for this border to appear above each menu element, but resize its horizontal lines accordingly.
Is this possible to do without having to use a lot of images [*i.e. either images of each type of menu size, or having to replace all menu items as images*] or (a lot of) CSS3?

The typical menu code is as follows:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If I where you, I will add the same images on roll to every items with the "background-size: cover;" css attribute. It will center your image.
Then, just hide all content that overflow your current hover tab

Answer (score 1):

Use `:after` pseudo along with CSS triangle set to `position: absolute;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zvLcB/) (Hover the menu to see the desired effect)

Explanation: Am using [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aafter) pseudo here, which will create a virtual element, and am setting that to `position: absolute;`, and than am using `bottom` and `left` properties to position the triangle which will be visible on `:hover`. Make sure you use `content: "";` which is important, also, this won't create a gutter on the element, if you are looking to create a gutter, than you might need `clip` property.

```
#nav {
    height: 30px;
    background: #999;
}

#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

#nav li a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li:hover:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -2px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```